# how to handle new requests after iswritable is false in netty?

Tags: java, netty

to prevent oom, I should control when iswrite is false. so which solution followed is best?

(1)
drop the requests after iswritable is false?

(2)
block the IO(worker) thread through while(iswritable ==false)?

(3)
write to db/log and then handle them when idle time?
(this solution maybe not right one for me due to I need low latency)

3ks

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `channelWritabilityChanged` method in your `ChannelInboundHandler` implementation as shown there:

- see one example [here](https://github.com/fredericBregier/netty/commit/8f704e6020de364b031a77e1ee403d3ae4d8e10d#diff-05521194a5927473777105c441f714b6) in the DiscardClientHandler (very same on server side) (you're not obliged to use the trafficshapping)
- see API manual [here](http://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelInboundHandler.html#channelWritabilityChanged(io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext))

So in resume:

Your handler should try to write or directly test the writability status, then using the event from `channelWritabilityChanged` continue to write what you need to send.

Note that if you send a file or chunk item, you could use the `ChunkedWriteHandler` in your pipeline, using then an object to write that extend the `ChunkedInput` class (see API [here](http://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/handler/stream/package-summary.html)).